# How can i get MakeWalk working

Tags: animation, export, armature, makehuman

I am doing a big animation project. I am doing some animation scenarios and I need to apply each one on different MakeHuman character (different men and women). So, once I finish the scenario, I export it under .bvh file. After that, I use the MakeWalk tools to load and retarget this scenario on a new person. Unfortunately, Mocap could not auto-detect aramture and show me this message [image: error].

I try with the proposed solution in MakeHuman website but they did not work. Here is my file [.blender](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34796)